# Powerbuilder word hangs while opening if same doc is opened

Tags: ms-word, ole, powerbuilder

Before opening the word document
i want to check whether same document is opened already or not.
If opened then i want to close
app.documents.open(as_doc_name)

Comment: word document already opened on my desktop so on running application the code get hanged
and prompt for three option :
1)read only file
2)create local copy and merge changes later 
3) no wait for file
so to avoid this condition i want to check my file word doc is opened already or not. If opened then close word document and open as new copy

Comment: ole_myobject.connecttonewobject("word.application")
 ole_myobject.visible=false
IF  ole_myobject.Documents.Count >= 1 THEN
   Ls_doc_name =  ole_myobject.ActiveDocument.Name
END IF
if Ls_doc_name =as_doc_name THEN
  ole_myobject.ActiveDocument.close(0)
end if
 ole_myobject.documents.open(as_doc_name)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
IF ole_myobject.Documents.Count >= 1 THEN
   ls_doc_name = ole_myobject.ActiveDocument.Name
END IF
```

Here you have help of its operation:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Word/Checkthecurrentdocumentcount.htm

Comment: Locate the document with: "For ... Next". This verifies all open documents.

Comment: Checked active document count is comming  zero but still i saw in taskbar winword.exe  is runnung. please provide the code to check all active word document in powerbuilder

Answer (score 0):

The code works. The following example will help you understand how to develop it:

Declare Instance Variables:

```
OLEObject ole_myobject
```

Event Open():

```
ole_myobject = CREATE OLEObject 
ole_myobject.connecttonewobject("word.application")
```

Code in buttom:

```
String ls_doc_name
String as_doc_name
String as_path_name

Long ll_ActiveDocument

as_path_name = "C:\"
as_doc_name = "Prueba.doc"

ole_myobject.visible=1

ll_ActiveDocument = ole_myobject.Documents.Count

IF ll_ActiveDocument >= 1 THEN 
    Ls_doc_name = ole_myobject.ActiveDocument.Name 
END IF 
if Ls_doc_name = as_doc_name THEN 
    ole_myobject.ActiveDocument.close(0) 
end if 
ole_myobject.documents.open(as_path_name + as_doc_name)
```

Remember "ole_myobject.ActiveDocument.close(0)" does not close Word, it only closes the document but the Word application continues to run.

Comment: ole_myobject.Documents.Count is showing Zero but still i am getting this error 

xxx.docx is locked for editing by user 
Do you want to:
1) Open a read Only Copy
2) Create a local copy and merge your changes later
3)Receive Notification when the Original Copy is available

Comment: Try doing the example I gave you, beware of the exact location of the connecttonewobject () function, an incorrect place always returns zero when using "ole_myobject.Documents.Count"

Comment: my code is similar to what you added above but problem is happening when word document get hanged and session got closed opnning new same and accessing the same document is cuasing the problem.